# How can I click the link in a Toaster message in Sahi Script

Tags: sahi

Upon completion of filling up a form , and clicking submit , a toaster message is generated (visible for only a few seconds)
How can I click the link in a Toaster message in Sahi Script ?

Comment: Just like any normal link click. If you want to add extra checks, just check if the link is available or not.

Comment: The scenario is something like this , a new object is created a form has been filled up . A toast message is given that the object has been created successfully . The toast message contains the identification number of the object created , which is unique and dynamic in nature . For example if the form has been filled up once then the ID of the object will be OB-0001 , when the form is filled second time , the ID will be OB-0002 and so on. This Toast message is available for only a few seconds

Comment: What is the exact issue then? You can't identify the dynamic created ID or that the toast message is available for small time?